# How should cross-platform login work with Parse server? (Getting invalid session token)

Tags: ios, express, parse-platform, authentication, parse-server

I'm working on a cross-platform app (iOS & web) that uses Parse server (and Parse iOS SDK on iOS). When switching between the iOS app and the web app, I get an "invalid session token" error that prevents any further calls to Parse from succeeding. In other words, here are the steps that lead to this error:

1. Sign up for an account on iOS
2. Send the app into the background (does not log you out)
3. Open the web app in a browser and log in
4. Either close the tab/browser or log out, it doesn't matter
5. Open the iOS app, and an invalid session token error will occur when trying to make any calls to Parse

The same thing happens in reverse as well, so if you starting sign-up on the web, then log in on iOS, then back to web again, calls to Parse will fail for the web app.

I can see that when logging in (or signing up) on one platform creates an entry in the `Sessions` table, and then logging in on another platform will replace that entry with a new one for that user. Then when returning to the other platform, the `Session` entry will be different (with a different token) causing the error.

What is the best way to deal with this? Do sessions need to be managed manually in such a case? Of course, I could just pop up an error for the user to inform them that their session has expired and has to log in again, but it would be much nicer not to do that.

So does each platform need its own `Session` or is there a way to share sessions?

I'm currently using Parse iOS SDK 1.14.4 with Parse Server 2.3.7. And in the iOS app, I am calling `enableRevocableSessionInBackground()`.

Comment: That is very strange, [this](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/2845) Github issue has more information on your error.
Why do you need to specifically call `enableRevocableSessionInBackground()`?

Comment: @Nick Ok, thanks. I'll look through that issue when I get the chance. Calling that method is required to migrate from the now-deprecated legacy session tokens. I tried commenting it out though, and it doesn't help. The other strange thing is, it works on the currently deployed production environment. This error I'm getting now is on dev. Not sure if it's a bug or not, or has something to do with the Parse server version on prod vs. dev (not sure what the prod version is at this time).

Comment: Check the Parse versions,  maybe that is the issue. Currently I have users with 3, 4 active sessions, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Second having no issues with multiple sessions for users. I'd definitely diff your config files to see if you've maybe changed something that inadvertently affected this and check the versions of parse-server.